# git submodules and directory structure

Tags: git

I have a directory structure something like:

```
root/
    files
    dir1/
        main-project-files
        main-project-subdirs/
    dir2/
```

I have another repository that i'd like to add to the mail project. It has a structure something like:

```
dir1/
    submodule-files
    submodule-subdirs/
```

The problem is that I want the `dir1` from both the main project and the external repository to be the same folder, but I don't really want the files in `dir1` that are part of the main project to be tracked as part of the repository. Ending with an overall structure like:

```
root/
    files
    dir1/
        main-project-files
        main-project-subdirs/
        submodule-files
        submodule-subdirs/
    dir2/
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: are you trying to have both `dir1` directories under `root/` in the same folder? Perhaps you can elaborate a little more?

Comment: I want to end with only 1 `dir1` directory.

Comment: @AdamT see question update.

Comment: ahh, i see now. a follow up quesition, do files from main project `dir1` have the same name as files from the `dir1` submodule files? it looks like you'd just have to add the files you want to ignore along with the directories. sorry if i'm still not following.

Comment: No, there's no name overlap at that level. I could just copy the files in, but how would I track changes from the upstream repository

Comment: have you considered a symbolic link to another directory? Basically git would track everything as a file, but it wouldn't track where the link is pointing to.

Comment: Yes, I've considered that, I was hoping there was a better way. But that may be what I end up doing.

Comment: ha, well, there it is :-) i don't think it's a bad solution though. why are you against it?

Answer (score 0):

What you would do is have a symbolic link in the directory that you want to track point to, or be pointed at from, the directory you don't want to track. If you don't want to track the symlink either you can add that to your gitignore. Git would then only view your tracked directory and know nothing about where the symlinc is pointing.

Comment: I don't want to ignore it. I want some of the files in dir1 to be tracked as part of the main project and some of them to tracked as part of a submodule (or something).

Comment: Will both directories be in the same folder? (With different names like `dir1` and `dir1_0`?)

Answer (score 0):

Git doesn't really have a facility for constructing intricate lists of exactly which files in which directories comes from which of some list of arbitrary histories.  I think the reasoning behind that is it'd be just as unnecessarily error-prone for humans to keep track of and validate the lists as it would be to describe what exactly can and can't be done with it.

Just keep everything that shares community and history in a repo set and clone from that as a submodule in everything else that uses it.  You get the same effect, with rules for which files are part of which history that are much, much easier to validate (let alone describe).